# What is the best way to sum a data with a horizontal and vertical criteria if there are text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to add cells with a horizontal and vertical criteria but Sumproduct() formula is out of the question as not all data are numbers. I am currently using MS office 2016

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your question is like this:

[image]

And this would be the formula:

```
=SUM(IF($B$1:$F$1=I$1;IF($A$2:$A$21=$H2;$B$2:$F$21)))
```

Comment: I can't seem to have it worked. Do you have any other formula?

Comment: Have a look on my update. I was confused by the columns headers not being the same in the 2 tables in your screenshot, although you mentioned horizontal and vertical criteria in the headline. The formula requires them to be the same to be able to match the corresponding column.

Comment: It worked, can you help me understand the formula? specially with the ;